# How to disable custom protocol handler for protractor?

Tags: selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, e2e-testing

I have a Protractor test suite for an application that uses a custom protocol handler to pass messages out of an iOS web view.

When testing it with protractor, how do I prevent the custom `window.location = "app://doThing";` message from breaking my tests? It shows the "Open xdg-open?" popup and doesn't continue with tests.

My protractor configuration looks like this:

```
exports.config = {
  ...,
  multiCapabilities: [ {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: { 
      args: [ '--lang=en', '--window-size=1024x768' ]
    },
    specs: 'test-*.js',
  } ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this in Chrome 60 by setting the preferences inside the chromeOptions block.

```
exports.config = {
  ...,
  multiCapabilities: [ {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: { 
      args: [ '--lang=en', '--window-size=1024x768' ],

      // Replace "app" with your app's custom scheme.
      prefs: { 
        protocol_handler: { 
          excluded_schemes: { 
            "app": true 
          } 
        } 
      },
    },
    specs: 'test-*.js',
  } ]
};
```

---

Before Chrome 60, I enforced a profile folder for the Chrome runner. You can do that by having a folder named "/chrome-profile" in the Chrome docker container for example, and adding one file in it named "Default State" with the following content:

```
{
    "protocol_handler": {
        "excluded_schemes": {
            "app": true
        }
    }
}
```

And after that, setting the Chrome user-data-dir flags as such:

```
exports.config = {
  ...,
  multiCapabilities: [{
     'browserName': 'chrome',
     'chromeOptions' : {
         args: ['--lang=en',
                '--window-size=1024,768',
                '--user-data-dir=/chrome-profile/']
       },
       specs: ['test-*.js']
   }]
};
```