# How to deny or block a chrome pop up while using java selenium with chromedriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, popup

I am facing the problem that each time my program wants to enter a specific website it appears a pop up by chrome which asks for permission to continue in an app, which i do not want to install. I either want to deny the permission or generally block it causing it to not appear at all.
I have already tested some solutions that were offered in similar posts, but i could not get them to work, I am a newbie and i would be very thankful for your help.

Here is my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void methodOne() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:...\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu ", "--window-size=1344,840","--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
        options.addArguments("incognito");
        options.addArguments("test-type");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Can you share a link to that web site?

Comment: not really, but you can imagine it to work like facebook and chrome is asking you to continue inside the facebook app instead of the browser.

Comment: I can also imagine posts with more details and I even have seen some. But you do not have to do that, it's Okay

Comment: I do not use Selenium, but this sounds like the protocol handler config.  You may have luck searching for how to disable the "protocol handler", such as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542179/how-to-disable-custom-protocol-handler-for-protractor

Answer (score 0):

```
public void invokeBrowser() {
        
        // Setting up Google Chrome options for no notification popup
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

        //Initializing the WebDriver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",chromeDriverLocation);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    }
```

Comment: the pop up is still appearing somehow, even though i followed your suggestion. :(